# What is this font on WhiteHouse.gov, and how can I use CSS to create this image?

Tags: html, css, fonts

This font in this image from the WhiteHouse looks very professional. What is the font? Is it just Times New Roman?

Also, does anybody know how to use CSS to create something just like the image below? (So I can keep everything else in that image but change the text)

Thanks!!

[image]
<sub>(source: [whitehouse.gov](http://www.whitehouse.gov/assets/hero/hero_bkgd_united_we_serve.jpg))</sub>

Comment: This is really a how to use photoshop question and not a programming question.

Comment: I was hoping I could at least get the font working in html/css without learning photoshop.

Comment: If it's a non standard font/oddball font, you can't be guaranteed that users will have it installed on their computer.  The only way to guarantee it actually renders correctly then is to use an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a font service like [WhatTheFont.com](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) to find a closest match.

As for your second question, you can create a table the size of your background image, and use css to set the background of the table to that. Afterwards, just input the text in the table cell and use

```
style="text-align: center;"
```

to center the text.

You might want to use Photoshop to wipe the original text in background, as noted above.

Comment: What ryanulit said - there's no justification for a table here, and I'd add the inline style is sub-optimal compared to CSS applied too.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [Garamond](http://www.identifont.com/show?M5).  It is the same font used in this document:

http://www.hud.gov/united-we-serve/united-we-serve.pdf

It is distinguishable by the fact that the vertical lines inside of the W cross over each other.

In order to use the font successfully on your web page, it has to be installed on the computer of the user viewing it.  Garamond is an Adobe font used on Apple Mac computers, and it's installed on my stock Windows XP computer, so I imagine almost everyone has it already.

Answer (score 1):

You should use what the font to identify it.

http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Answer (score 1):

You can create this type of look using your programming skils (thus avoiding photoshop) by using SIFR. It really works great with dynamic sites. We use it often (see h1s [here](http://www.delphicsage.com/home/about.aspx)). Info on SIFR is [here](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/What+is+sIFR)

Answer (score 0):

That text is part of the image:
http://www.whitehouse.gov/assets//hero/hero_bkgd_united_we_serve.jpg

Comment: Do you think I could use that font in HTML/CSS?

Comment: If users have that font installed on their machines, otherwise you have to have them download it and install it...

Comment: If you want to create a banner, perhaps you should just have the image created on your server.

Consider using a graphics library like GD to programatically add the text to the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Cufon may provide what you need to embed a non-system font in a HTML page:
http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

There are a few caveats when it comes to licensing, and a few browser issues, but it works fairly well for the most part - certainly better than sifr.

Answer (score 0):

Garamond can now be licensed through Adobe for use with @font-face through TypeKit.

So, with a bit of Font-face and CSS3 magic, you could quite easily create this effect without resorting to images.